# Proxy class and correct syntax c++

Tags: c++, class, syntax, proxy-classes

Let's say we got class A and method B... The correct Syntax is `return type A::B() {...}`

Now imagine, we have a class B inside the class A and plus method C that has the inner class B (proxy class due to [ ][ ] operator) as a "return type". How do I do that?

`A::B A::B::C() {}` does not work neither does `B A::B::C() {}`

Plus I'd like to have it in `.cpp` and `.h` file.

Comment: Please post the real code with real error messages you are getting.

Comment: "but unfortunately I don't have time to deal with this" - erm what?

Comment: It's a school project and the dead-line is near. I am sorry if I put this in some kind of a rude way.

Comment: The only error I get is "error: ‘B’ does not name a type"

Comment: If the dead-line is near, spend every minute to solve it yourself! Or did you wasted long time and find yourself cornered? ... Anyway, if you want a solution, we will need to see the minimal program which reproduces your problem. It's hard to suggest something while walking in the dark.

Comment: Exactly. I wasted a kind of huge amount of time looking for a solution. Those two I mentioned are the only ones I came up with.

Comment: Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/b6xBVTaV (line 55 is where the problem is).

Comment: Time looking for a solution is not a wasted time. You gain a lot of experience and you will find the solution to the next problem faster. By "wasted time" I meant not actually doing anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're referring to the wrong scope for your `operator[]`. Perhaps you meant:

```
CScreen::Proxy CScreen::operator[] (int index) const 
{
  return Proxy ( m_playground, index, m_y );
}
```

Comment: This project is starting to annoy me. Thank you. I don't understand how could I miss this.

Comment: Unless it's a project requirement, you can consider using `operator()` instead that takes 2 parameters `x, y`. This way you can avoid the proxy class altogether. It might help simplify things.